# Pyramid invoking a sub request

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to implement a batch request method in pyramid.  I see in the docs that it's done with

```
subrequest = Request.blank('/relative/url')
request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest)
```

I'm just wondering how do you pass along the headers and cookies? Is it already done for you or is it

```
request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest, cookies=request.cookies, headers=request.headers)
```

What about parameters for different methods?  The docs only have a `POST` keyword arg.

I feel like the docs are a little vague, or I can't find the correct docs on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Nice question, after having dug through the docs for about 30 mins I can only agree with you on that the docs are not super clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm just wondering how do you pass along the headers and cookies?*

From http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/subrequest.html#subrequest-chapter :

> The pyramid.request.Request.invoke_subrequest() API accepts two
>   arguments: a positional argument request that must be provided, and
>   use_tweens keyword argument that is optional; it defaults to False.

This tells us that the constructor only wants a `Request` object, and optionally a value for `use_tweens`, so no, this

```
request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest, cookies=request.cookies, headers=request.headers)
```

will not work.

Then, from http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/subrequest.html

> It's a poor idea to use the original request object as an argument to
>   invoke_subrequest(). You should construct a new request instead as
>   demonstrated in the above example, using
>   pyramid.request.Request.blank(). **Once you've constructed a request
>   object, you'll need to massage it to match the view callable you'd
>   like to be executed during the subrequest. This can be done by
>   adjusting the subrequest's URL, its headers, its request method, and
>   other attributes. The documentation for pyramid.request.Request
>   exposes the methods you should call and attributes you should set on
>   the request you create to massage it into something that will actually
>   match the view you'd like to call via a subrequest.**

So basically, you need to configure your request before you pass it to `invoke_subrequest()`.

Luckily there is [an entire page that documents the Request class](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/request.html#request-module). There we can find a whole lot options to configure it, etc.

---

*What about parameters for different methods? The docs only have a POST keyword arg.*

Also on the Request class documentation page, there is this

> **method**
>
> Gets and sets the REQUEST_METHOD key in the environment.

And on http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/viewconfig.html I found

> request_method This value can be a string (typically "GET", "POST",
>   "PUT", "DELETE", or "HEAD") representing an HTTP REQUEST_METHOD

I must agree with you that the documentation is a little vague here and there, but I assume you can use it like this

```
request.method = 'POST'
# Or
request.method = 'GET'
# Etc.
```

---

**Summary**

You'll want to do it like this

```
subrequest = Request.blank('/relative/url')
# Configure the subrequest object
# set headers and other options you need.
request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest)
```

**Note**

I am aware this is not a 100% complete answer with some code that you can copy paste and it'll just work (especially regarding configuring the request object), but I think this answer contains some information that, at the very least, will get you on the right track and I hope it will be of some help to you.

Comment: You got me going in the right direction thank you.  I'm getting `PredicateMismatch` now but that's probably a separate question.

Comment: Works great but I have a little issue when I need to use the request.dbsession in the subrequest. When I call a query, it raise NoTransaction()
transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction

Is it possible to avoid this error?

Comment: @MichaelLane honestly I have no clue. I haven't done python in a long time

Comment: Ok, no problem, thanks for answer. I'm going to do a new issue.

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me. It copies all (headers, cookies, query string, post parameters, etc.):

```
def subrequest(request, path):
    subreq = request.copy()
    subreq.path_info = path
    response = request.invoke_subrequest(subreq)
    return response
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late, but based on the above two answers here is how I did this. I didn't quite like the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687653/pyramid-invoking-a-sub-request#answer-24199503) to just copy everything. Looking at the documentation of the [blank() method](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.blank) there is a `kw` argument and it says

> All necessary keys will be added to the environ, but the values you pass in will take precedence. If you pass in base_url then wsgi.url_scheme, HTTP_HOST, and SCRIPT_NAME will be filled in from that value.

Assuming that the view's request contains the right header information and cookies that you need for your subrequest, you can use the following code:

```
@view_config( ... )
def something(request):
    ...
    kwargs = { "cookies": request.cookies,                                  
               "host"   : request.host,                                     
             }                                                              
    req = Request.blank("/relative/url", **kwargs)
    resp = request.invoke_subrequest(req)
```

Other header information (e.g. `accept`, `accept_encoding`, etc.) are properties of [pyramid.request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html) objects, and can be added to the `kwargs` dictionary like shown in the code snippet above.

The object returned by `invoke_subrequest()` is a Response object documented [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response).